# Detect modal window on top of WKWebView in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

How can i detect that a modal window pops up on WKWebView. I need to detect because I need to disable the back and menu button?

I have used the WKWebView delegates, but none is called when modal window pops up. WKWebView delegates are called only when browser reloads.

Please find the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Your modal window seems to be a pure Javascript / HTML implementation. So you have no hooks in iOS to catch these event homogeneously. If you know or control the corresponding Javascript code you can inject additional Javascript code from iOS to send custom events on opening and closing these windows.

Comment: Thanks @clemens for your prompt reply. I will look into your suggestion and  try to work it round.

Comment: You should take a look on [message handlers and user scripts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller) too.

Comment: okay..sure I will have a look :)

Comment: Hello @clemens following link helped me to solve my issue, as per your suggestion to look into message handlers and user scripts topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827368/swift-webview-how-to-call-correctly-swift-code-from-javascript